# How can I adjust the gamma level of my display on Windows 7 w/ a script?

Tags: windows, powershell

I was hoping to create a script or two to be able to adjust the gamma level of my display with the push of a button. Currently, the process is opening the display, clicking on Calibrate color, nexting my way through about 20 screens, and adjusting the value of the gamma.

Does anyone know of a way to shorten this process? I don't care which technology is used but I guess my intuition says powershell might be the way. I want to be able to switch the gamma level to 100% quickly and also to switch it back to the default value of 50% quickly.

So, essentially hoping for something like:

```
$GammaObject.SetValue(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, you can edit in in registry:
http://jonls.dk/2010/09/windows-gamma-adjustments/

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ICM]
"GdiIcmGammaRange"=dword:00000100
```

To edit registry using powershell:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/04/02/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/

Comment: Doesn't that first article say that the value is just the range of values and not the actual value? I'm looking to adjust the actual value and not the range of possible values. Thank you

Comment: How about trying it first, for experiment. I'm not expert in setting gamma correction. If that is not enough, you can still see his source code in GitHub. He said, in Windows, there are limitations.

Comment: I changed the registry value with no visible effect to my display, so I didn't really think changing those worked. I did find another bit of related code for c++ that might work and I'll try to link it later when I have more time.